# Alamofire throwing errors in swift 2.2

Tags: alamofire, swift2, xcode7.3

I did try to update Alamofire framework using cocoa pods.
yesterday it was working fine

how can i fix this..?

I am using `cocoa pods`

```
use_frameworks!
target "SampleTest" do
pod 'Alamofire', :git => 'https://github.com/Alamofire/Alamofire.git', :branch => ‘master’
```

after opening

[image]

Comment: Are you sure you're using Xcode 7.3? From the screenshot it looks like Xcode doesn't recognize `#selector` which would mean you're using Xcode 7.2 or lower.

Comment: # tags arent removed in updated version..?

Answer (score 0):

open podfile and use:

platform :ios, ‘8.0’
use_frameworks!
pod 'Alamofire', '~> 3.4'

after input on terminal and enter text

pod install

Answer (score 0):

I was getting 352 errors just after adding it as a pod. 
On github I found this as requirements.

```
iOS 9.0+ / Mac OS X 10.11+ / tvOS 9.0+ / watchOS 2.0+
Xcode 8.0+
Swift 3.0+
```

I am pointing to version 3.5.0 and I am able to build my project.